# manually validate code in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In eclipse, I have disabled the reporting of problems as I type. Because I found all the editor activity too distracting.
When I am finished making the changes, I want to have it checked/validated by eclipse. I do this by saving the file: problems get reported then.

My question: is there a way to make eclipse check the code without saving?

Comment: I guess no, because the Java code is validate by the Eclipse compiler which is executed on save.

Comment: thanks, good to know.